# delete from database except that filter

Tags: mysql, sql, filtering

I have a database where people via a command sends information and its stored in the database. The same person can have many reports per day and the next query shows only the latest:

```
SELECT
    r1.id,
    r1.nickname,
    r1.fecha,
    r1.bestia1,
    r1.bestia2,
    r1.bestia3,
    r1.bestia4,
    r1.bestia5
FROM
    reporte AS r1
INNER JOIN
    ( SELECT
          nickname,
          MAX(fecha) AS max_date
      FROM
          reporte
      GROUP BY
          nickname ) AS latests_reports ON latests_reports.nickname = r1.nickname AND latests_reports.max_date = r1.fecha
ORDER BY
    r1.fecha DESC
```

But now I want to delete all the records except the records returned from the previous query, how can I do it?

Comment: Delete from where? Only from `reporte` or in cascade?

Comment: i want to delete from reporte db, in order to have only one record per user and per day

Comment: then the naive way would be to just select the `id` and use the query as the `where id not in` clause of a `delete` query.

Comment: this above query may not show only the latest, if any nickname has more then one "reporte" in the same max date ("fecha")  there will be more then one result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you'd do this as a set of steps, but it may be possible to single-step it by:

```
DELETE FROM reporte
WHERE id not in
(
  SELECT a.id FROM(
    SELECT r1.id
    FROM reporte AS r1 
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT nickname, MAX(fecha) AS max_date 
    FROM reporte GROUP BY nickname ) AS latests_reports 
    ON latests_reports.nickname = 
    r1.nickname AND latests_reports.max_date = r1.fecha 
  ) a
)
```

You need the a.id query in there otherwise MySQL will complain that it can't update the reporte table

As separate steps:

```
    CREATE TABLE to_keep AS
    SELECT r1.id
    FROM reporte AS r1 
    INNER JOIN 
    ( SELECT nickname, MAX(fecha) AS max_date FROM reporte GROUP BY nickname ) AS latests_reports 
    ON 
      latests_reports.nickname = r1.nickname AND 
      latests_reports.max_date = r1.fecha

    DELETE r.* FROM reporte r LEFT JOIN to_keep k ON r.id = k.id WHERE k.id IS NULL

    DROP TABLE to_keep
```

Comment: your code looks good but i dont know how to exactly make set of steps, i need execute the first query and then the 2nd query? thanks in advance

Comment: It's either or - you choose whether to do the top one ot the bottom code block. The bottom code block has 3 steps, you'll need to exec them individually, or script things up so they run as a batch (hint: DELIMITER)

Comment: thanks, i am usin phpmyadmin to run it and when i execute the first query it says "undeclared variable: to_delete"

Comment: thanks! the second code step by step works fine, the first query deleted all my data

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: I have updated the query from `EXITS()` to `NOT EXISTS()`
You want to delete all records except the records your query listed. This is your query :
:

```
DELETE FROM Reporte WHERE NOT EXISTS 
        (
            SELECT 1 FROM
            (
                SELECT r1.id, 
                FROM reporte AS r1 
                INNER JOIN ( SELECT nickname, MAX(fecha) AS max_date  FROM reporte GROUP BY nickname ) AS latests_reports  
                    ON latests_reports.nickname =  r1.nickname 
                    AND latests_reports.max_date = r1.fecha 
            ) r WHERE Reporte.Id= r.Id
        )
```

Comment: it says:#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'FROM reporte AS r1 
                INNER JOIN ( SELECT nickname, MAX(fecha) AS' en la linea 6